# How to show the connector lines as default?

Tags: fancytree

Hi there i have just started using this jquery tree. and was wondering if there is any property I can set to make the connecting line visible all the time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There isn't a property available in the options set connecting lines to visible all the time, but you can add a class to the object with the `fancytree-container` class to turn on connectors. If you want to have connections visible all the time, you could add the class to the `fancytree-container` right after you initialize the fancytree:

```
$("#tree").fancytree({
   // initialization options
});

$(".fancytree-container").addClass("fancytree-connectors");
```

[This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97Lt4eew/) demonstrates how to toggle the `fancytree-connectors` class on the `fancytree-container` object.