# No connectors nor icons visible for jQuery FancyTree

Tags: jquery, css, fancytree

I'm trying to implement a web-based folder browser using the FancyTree jquery plugin. After some teething problems, I have it working quite well. The only problem is that FancyTree doesn't display any connector lines or icons. Strictly text only, with + and - icons for expand and collapse, respectively. I had imagined such a file-system oriented plugin to have default icons for e.g. closed and open folder, etc. so I have not yet specified custom icons, but the connector lines bother me more.

I cobbled together my FancyTree source from its GitHub repo, and my source folder looks as follows. This is from cherry-picking the source, because the `dist` folder for FancyTree is a bit sparse:

[image]

This is how I reference the styles and scripts. Dev only for brevity:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />

<link href="~/lib/fancytree/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/lib/fancytree/jquery-ui.structure.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/lib/fancytree/jquery-ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/lib/fancytree/skin-bootstrap/ui.fancytree.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

The extra styles came with my minimmal custom download for jQuery UI, a dependency of FancyTree. Script:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/fancytree/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/fancytree/jquery.fancytree-all.js"></script>
```

I'm only imagining a missing or wrong `images` location, but surely this should use glyphicons style icons. I have not specified any custom icons, but expected defaults. If I can get custom icons working then my real concern is the missing connector lines.

BREAKING: 
If I force connectrors to show according to this [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41877076/how-to-show-the-connector-lines-as-default), by adding a class as soon as the tree is initiated:

```
$(".fancytree-container").addClass("fancytree-connectors");
```

I get vertical portions of connectors all over, but nothing visible on the horizontal.
, just the text, often far indented and less readable than a tree with lines.

Comment: Would you be able to reproduce this issue in a codepen or similar ?

Comment: @ProfK did you get a chance to check the answer? Did it help? Cheers :)

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar It helped fine, but the connectors are not how I'd like them, I'd like longer horizontal ones, but that's outside of your concern. Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The icons are not displayed because you try to use bootstrap skin but you didnt load bootstrap css

Add a reference to `boostrap.css` before the skin css file:

```
<link href="~/path/to/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/lib/fancytree/skin-bootstrap/ui.fancytree.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Other than that, dont forget to add these two settings on load:

- `extensions` - specifying you want to use `glyph` extension
- `glyph` - specifying you want `bootstrap3` preset

Something like:

```
$("#tree").fancytree({
    extensions: ["glyph"],
    glyph: {
        preset: "bootstrap3"
    },
    checkbox: true,
    source: ...,
    .
    .
    .
});
```

See Bootstrap theme [example](http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/index.html#sample-ext-bootstrap.html) from Fancytree Example Browser

See this **[simplified example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xXYmdp)**

---

**BTW**

You can switch to a different skin that supports connectors by referencing it instead:

```
<!-- <link href="~/lib/fancytree/skin-bootstrap/ui.fancytree.css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
<link href="~/lib/fancytree/skin-win8/ui.fancytree.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

And set connectors using:

```
$(".fancytree-container").addClass("fancytree-connectors");
```

See themes that support connectors in this [example](http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/#sample-default.html) from Fancytree Example Browser

See this [simplified example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gGvEqj) (win8 theme and connectors)